# Is it possible to rewrite the silly2 example from the Tactics chapter of the SF book using 'rewrite' instead of 'apply'?

Tags: coq

```
Theorem silly2 : forall(n m o p : nat),
     n = m ->
     (forall (q r : nat), q = r -> [q;o] = [r;p]) ->
     [n;o] = [m;p].
Proof.
  intros n m o p eq1 eq2.
  apply eq2.
  apply eq1.
Qed.
```

The [SF book](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/current/Tactics.html#lab127) implies that it would be possible to do the above using rewrite, but I just do not see how. Any idea how it would be possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to prove it with `rewrite (eq2 ? ? ?)` if you properly fill the `?`. Be sure to understand what is going on in order to improve your understanding of Coq.

[Hint: try `pose proof (eq2 o)` and see what it does]

Answer (score 2):

Here are 3 different versions of this. The first one I figured out on my own before seeing the reply by ejgallego in a different context once I realized what the `rewrite` error messages meant.

```
Theorem silly2 : forall(n m o p : nat),
     n = m ->
     (forall (q r : nat), q = r -> [q;o] = [r;p]) ->
     [n;o] = [m;p].
Proof.
  intros n m o p eq1 eq2.
  rewrite eq2 with (r := m).
  - reflexivity.
  - rewrite eq1. reflexivity.
Qed.
```

The second one seem to be a rewrite with a function application as per ejgallego's suggestion.

```
Theorem silly2' : forall(n m o p : nat),
     n = m ->
     (forall (q r : nat), q = r -> [q;o] = [r;p]) ->
     [n;o] = [m;p].
Proof.
  intros n m o p eq1 eq2.
  rewrite (eq2 n m).
  - reflexivity.
  - rewrite eq1. reflexivity.
Qed.
```

The third one uses `pose proof` which seem to be doing function application on the hypothesis without rewriting the goal as in the above.

```
Theorem silly2'' : forall(n m o p : nat),
     n = m ->
     (forall (q r : nat), q = r -> [q;o] = [r;p]) ->
     [n;o] = [m;p].
Proof.
  intros n m o p eq1 eq2.
  pose proof (eq2 n m).
  apply H.
  apply eq1.
Qed.
```

Comment: In the third version you can also use `specialize` instead of `pose proof`. Technically, the third version doesn't use `rewrite`, though.

Comment: This would be my proof: `now rewrite (eq2 _ _ eq1)`. Note that in this case, I would declare the two first arguments of `eq2` implicit so I would just do `rewrite (eq2 eq1)`. Cheers.